# Does a real user ID which identifies the user who created the process?

Tags: bash, login

As per the section [The Persona of a Process](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Process-Persona.html#Process-Persona) of the glibc manual:

```
A process also has a real user ID which identifies the user who created the process ...
```

So to verify this, I ran the command:

```bsh
ps -eo cmd,ruid,euid | grep 'bash\|login'
```

then show (the uid of lgd account is 1000):

```
login --lgd              0      0
-bash                 1000   1000
```

Why isn't the ruid of `bash` the value 0 since its creator `login` belong to root user ?
Do I misunderstand it or does `login` invoke functions like `setuid()` to change the ruid of bash ?

Comment: Yes ! If username & password match, then login will fork and the child process will setuid prior to exec-ing bash.

Comment: Yeah, I have just browsed the login source code `login.c` .  It really invoke setuid() after fork().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`login` does indeed change the user id before running `bash`. In the shadow implementation, you can see this [here](https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/fd5945e53342cf5017ca3157518fa69f8ac3e133/src/login.c#L1244), with quite a lot of further setup before [the shell is started](https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/fd5945e53342cf5017ca3157518fa69f8ac3e133/src/login.c#L1340).

The persona difference described in the link you referenced is really relevant for setuid programs. If you make a copy of `id`, then make it setuid, `id -u` and `id -ru` will show different values, the latter being the user id which started the process.